# Как задать хеш для nonce в конфигурации nginx для включения CSP

Tags: javascript, nginx, безопасность, хеширование, md5

Добрый день. У меня возникла проблема с включением CSP на сайт. Я включил Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only в файле nginx.conf. В консоли вышла следующая ошибка

> adsbygoogle.js:37 [Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src http://example.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-c+dT7QO/wB/DJJUeioTL/YNq09s5o1WF1vk5RjJU/4I='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. (anonymous function) @ adsbygoogle.js:37

Я искал решение проблемы. Но везде советуют включить `unsafe-inline`. Я думаю, что это небезопасно. А более надёжным вариантом будет использование `nonce-`. Но для этого нужно включить генерацию хеша в конфигах nginx и передавать её в файлы, чтобы приставлять к скриптам. Но я не знаю, как это реализовать. Думал даже попробовать md5 (секретное слово+дата сегодняшняя). Но и это тоже нельзя использовать в конфигурации nginx. Прошу помочь с вопросом или хоть дать ссылку на статью. Заранее прошу не рекомендовать включение CSP в PHP-файлах.

Comment: При чём тут nginx?

Comment: add_header Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only "default-src 'self';